# Add Double Quotes before and after the string including Lines

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add inverted commas before and after the string and Lines by replacing the Comma. I have below string and using this for inverted commas.

```
Char(34)&A1&Char(34)
```

But when i add this formula to add lines then it adds double inverted commas. Any solution to this problem will be appreciated.

My formula `=CHAR(34)&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10))&CHAR(34)` the string becomes like this

```
"""Completed      BDM 01-24-2019
 DDM 10-31-2021
 """
```

[image]

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUGqUzIDsMLgj7v6QzStLBAskG0FwcmIRlvcIzx0G9o/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Char(34)&TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "),",",CHAR(10)))&Char(34))
```

- At first, the multiple spaces and the last comma are replaced with a single space. And the comma is replaced with `CHAR(10)`. And, `Char(34)` is added to the 1st and last character.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> But i just "want" these inverted commas 1 time at beginning and end of the string not twice. When i copy any cell from the formula and paste into the Word document in converts the inverted commas "From this" to ""this"" but i only want "this"

In the current stage, when the line break is included in the cell value, when the cell is copied and pasted, it seems that it becomes `"""test"""`. In that case, when you want to copy and paste the cell values like `"test"` instead of `"""test"""`, how about the following sample formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10,", $",""),","),TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "),",",CHAR(10))),Char(34)&TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "))&Char(34)))
```

In this sample formula, the double quotes are not shown in the cell. And, the value without the line break is enclosed by `"`. But when you copy and paste the cell value, the value is enclosed by the single double-quote.

Comment: Thank you very much for the above solution. Sir i have attached an screen shot where i am pasting this note. I have pasted `2nd` and `3rd` from the sheet. you can check where lines are added there `2 inverted commas` are being pasted and `without line` there is `1  inverted commas`. I am looking for just "like" inverted commas not twice.  https://ibb.co/Mkw0YL5

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `i have attached an screen shot where i am pasting this note. I have pasted 2nd and 3rd from the sheet. you can check where lines are added there 2 inverted commas are being pasted and without line there is 1 inverted commas. I am looking for just "like" inverted commas not twice.`. About your goal, I had thought that the column of "Result Looking for" is the result you expected. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sir I do apologize for my poor English. But i just "want"  these inverted commas 1 time at beginning and end of the string not twice. When i copy any cell from the formula and paste into the Word document in converts the inverted commas `"From this`"  to `""this""` but i only want `"this"`

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the values like `"this"` instead of `"""test"""`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are right Sir!

Comment: Thank you for repliyng. In that case, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script. @HSHO When Google Apps Script is used, your expeted values can be created as a text file. By this, you can copy and paste the values to your Word document. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Nope Sir still same problem is persisting `"""Completed GBM 01-03-2022
 KQM 05-24-2021
 DOP 01-03-2022"""` I would appreciate if the solution can be in the formula shape.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Nope Sir still same problem is persisting """Completed GBM 01-03-2022  KQM 05-24-2021  DOP 01-03-2022"""`, in this case, did you use my sample script? When I tested my sample script, `"test"` can be copied and pasted. So I cannot understand your current situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. In the current stage, when the line break is included in the cell value, when the cell is copied and pasted, it seems that it becomes `"""test"""`.  In that case, how about `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "),",",CHAR(10))))`? In this case, the double quotes are not shown in the cell. But when you copy and paste the cell value, the value is enclosed by the single double-quote. How about this?

Comment: I want to copy paste the each cell to note pad where additional inverted are pasted when i copy paste the cell.

Comment: Sir its not working for those cell which does not have `Line` but working for others

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, how about `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "),","),TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "),",",CHAR(10))),Char(34)&TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A10," {2,}|, $"," "))&Char(34)))`? By this, the value without the line break is enclosed by `"`. In this case, that is `"test"` instead of `"""test"""`.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I added the sample formula in my answer.